# Finding frequency of unique array elements by using single pointer

Tags: c, strings, pointers

I am supposed to find the frequency of the unique array elements of a character array via a user defined function like **int *unique(char *s)**,  which takes a pointer to a character and returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated  array of integers.

There are some constraints. I cannot use additional array nor any array indexing. Only pointer arithmetic is allowed. My solution is as follows:

```
 int *uniqueCount(char *s)
{
int a=0,k,p;
for(k=0;*(s+k);k++)
{
    for(p=k+1;*(s+p);p++)
    {
        if(*(s+k)==*(s+p)) break;
     }
    if(*(s+p)==0) a++;
}
int *arr,i=0;
arr=malloc(sizeof(int)*a);
for(k=0;*(s+k);k++)
{
    *(arr+i)=1;
    for(p=k+1;*(s+p);p++)
    {
        if(*(s+k)!='*'&&*(s+k)==*(s+p)){
            *(s+p)='*';
            *(arr+i)+=1;
        }
     }
     if(i<a-1) i++;
     else break;
}
return arr;
}
```

Some problems I face with my function:

**(i)** How to use the function in an actual program, like receiving the returned integer pointer and printing values.

**(ii)**  I am changing the array element into **"*"** in second part of function. I want to avoid it.

I know that I've made a complex function difficult to comprehend.If there is a more optimized and simple solution,  it would be helpful.

Thanks...

Comment: This code is very difficult to review because it isn't indented properly. Is it possible for you to reformat the code? Your first problem makes the question off-topic because it lacks concrete context, and possibly because the code wasn't tested so it might be broken.

Answer (score 3):

**Please** improve the variable names - it's not at all obvious what `a`, `k` and `p` are (and conventionally, `p` is usually used for a small-scope pointer, not an integer).

**Always** check whether `malloc()` (or `calloc()`, or `realloc()`) returns a non-null pointer before dereferencing.

The algorithm is so opaque that I'm not going to attempt to unravel it.  It's nowhere near suitable for production use.

BTW, it's misleading to claim that you don't use array indexing when there's clearly `*(arr+i)` in a couple of places and `*(s+p)` in a couple more.  Just changing the syntax doesn't stop that being a cheat.

Comment: I think the question is off-topic so I'm not sure an answer is appropriate.

Comment: I felt there was enough to review, but it's not a strong conviction.  Anyway, an answer won't stop the question being closed, so feel free to VTC there, @pacman

Comment: FYI, great review.

Comment: We should downvote this, but I'll make an exception https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8945/how-to-prevent-people-from-answering-off-topic-questions How else could this site see its first Lifeboat :p